# Tracking both internal and external email opens and clicks with Amazon SES, Lambda and S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I'm about to enable tracking on our emails - both one-to-one emails sent by our sales reps but also campaign emails we send to our lists.

I have looked at multiple different services for handling email tracking. Services like Mixmax (https://www.mixmax.com) is at one side of the spectrum offering good tools for one-to-one emails and services like SendGrid (https://www.sendgrid.com) is at the other end offering an infrastructure to send (a lot) of emails to our lists.

However, in order to avoid 1) paying for features we do not use (and thus overprice for tracking), 2) allow sales reps to use whatever email client/setup they want (some prefer Gmail others Outlook, many use mobile on the go), and 3) to be able to distinguish between internal and external opens and clicks, I’d like to put our tracking efforts just before/after the SMTP layer, so to speak. Therefore I'm looking at Amazon SES to do the job.

On top of mind I see the process of sending an email as:

1. An email is written by a sales rep or programatically (e.g. for a campaign).
2. Before sending it we replace all links (with our own redirecting to the original URLs) for tracking clicks and add a 1 pixel image to the email for tracking opens.
3. The email is delivered.

[Now we know that all opens and clicks are external]

4. The recipient writes a reply and sends it our way.
5. When it hits our servers we replace all links (the ones we originally created when the email was sent the first time) with new ones and do the same to the 1 pixel image.

[Now we know that all opens and clicks are internal]

Repeating the steps above on every send/receive - and for every recipient of the email so that the same 1 pixel image won’t be opened by 4 different recipients.

My question is: How would I arrive at a setup as described above with SES? For now only tracking of outgoing emails is supported and receiving with SES is currently limited to an S3 bucket (if I want to support attachments, I guess).

Should I skip SES' tracking functionality and write my own Lambdas for taking care of tracking for both outgoing and ingoing? And then basically do:

1. Email is created (in Gmail or Outlook by sales rep, by code for campaigns).
2. Email is sent to/stored in S3 bucket.
3. Email is processed by Lambda.
4. Email is sent to recipient through SES (without tracking).
5. Reply is received through SES.
6. Reply is stored in S3 bucket.
7. Reply is processed by Lambda.
8. Reply is sent to recipient through SES (without tracking).

Any hints are appreciated!